# How to show null or empty column when relative row does not exsist in joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the data from another table by use the joins, i want to show **competitor_name** column as empty/"" which is in the joined table *frbl1ozme_erp_crm_deals_competitors* when relative row in join table is not exist.

But the problem is it does not show the rows which don't exist in *frbl1ozme_erp_crm_deals_competitors* , i tried the CASE aswell in group but it does not work and i dont want to use *sub queries* as it is much slower than *joins*

the query which gave results or for only existing rows is below, can you please guide me how can i join with exist or show NULL or empty for non existing joined rows

```
SELECT
  ep.`display_name` AS office_coordinator, 
  cd.`owner_id` AS owner_id, um.`meta_value` AS sales_zone, 
  wep.`company` AS client_name, weps.`first_name` AS first_name,
  weps.`last_name` AS last_name, 
  weps.`user_id` AS client_personal_user_id, 
  wep.`user_id` AS client_user_id, cd.`company_id` AS company_id,
  cd.`contact_id` AS contact_id, cd.created_at AS deal_date,
  cd.`id` AS deal_id, cd.`title` AS deal_title, 
  pm.meta_value AS order_no, ps.`title` AS deal_status,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT compete.competitor_name separator ',') AS competitor,
  '' AS remarks 
FROM `frbl1ozme_erp_crm_deals` AS cd 
INNER JOIN `frbl1ozme_users` AS ep ON ep.`id` = cd.`owner_id` 
LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_erp_crm_deals_competitors` AS compete 
  ON compete.`deal_id` = cd.`id`
LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_erp_crm_deals_participants` AS ecp 
  ON ecp.`people_id` = cd.`contact_id` 
INNER JOIN `frbl1ozme_erp_crm_deals_pipeline_stages` AS ps 
  ON ps.`id` = cd.`stage_id` 
LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_erp_peoples` AS wep ON wep.`id`= cd.`company_id` 
LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_erp_peoples` AS weps ON weps.`id`= cd.`contact_id` 
LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_postmeta` AS pm 
  ON pm.`post_id` = cd.`id` AND pm.`meta_key` = '_erp_deal_order' 
LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_usermeta` AS um 
  ON um.`user_id` = ep.`id` AND um.`meta_key` = 'sales_zone' 
WHERE cd.`deleted_at` IS NULL 
  AND cd.`won_at` IS NULL 
  AND cd.`lost_at` IS NULL
Order by deal_id DESC
```

Comment: Of course not.  You are inner joining to that table and it is the first in the `from` list, so those are the rows you get.

Comment: The query is malformed. There's no `GROUP BY` clause but there's an aggregated column. The result is unpredictable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff dear but i dont user INNER JOIN for subjective table, frbl1ozme_erp_crm_deals_competitors , i use LEFT JOIN as you can see in the above mentioned query

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks bro, let me try that group thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for suggestions, so there was an issue with the query is as below as guided above

1. There was an inner join with the *users* table due to which all rows may not comes
2. There was *Group by* missing which can make the results tighten

so i sorted the  above issues and it gives a good result, following is the corrected query.

```
SELECT ep.`display_name` AS office_coordinator, cd.`owner_id` AS owner_id, cd.created_by as created_by, cd.expected_close_date, um.`meta_value` AS sales_zone, wep.`company` AS client_name, weps.`first_name` AS first_name, weps.`last_name` AS last_name, weps.`user_id` AS client_personal_user_id, wep.`user_id` AS client_user_id, cd.`company_id` AS company_id, cd.`contact_id` AS contact_id, cd.created_at AS deal_date, cd.`id` AS deal_id, cd.`title` AS deal_title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pm.meta_value separator ',') AS order_no, ps.`title` AS deal_status, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT compete.competitor_name separator ',') AS competitor, '' AS remarks 

FROM `frbl1ozme_erp_crm_deals` AS cd 

LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_users` AS ep ON ep.`id` = cd.`owner_id` 

LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_erp_crm_deals_competitors` AS compete ON compete.`deal_id` = cd.`id`

LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_erp_crm_deals_participants` AS ecp ON ecp.`people_id` = cd.`contact_id` 

LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_erp_crm_deals_pipeline_stages` AS ps ON ps.`id` = cd.`stage_id` 

LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_erp_peoples` AS wep ON wep.`id`= cd.`company_id` 

LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_erp_peoples` AS weps ON weps.`id`= cd.`contact_id` 

LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_postmeta` AS pm ON pm.`post_id` = cd.`id` AND pm.`meta_key` = '_erp_deal_order' 

LEFT JOIN `frbl1ozme_usermeta` AS um ON um.`user_id` = ep.`id` AND um.`meta_key` = 'sales_zone' 

WHERE cd.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND cd.`won_at` IS NULL AND cd.`lost_at` IS NULL 

GROUP BY deal_id

Order by deal_id DESC
```